/dev/sda is present but /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 are missing
I have a file.img file which was obtained by running dd if=/dev/sda of=file.img. This was done on a device with two partitions, /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2.
In order to flash a new device with the same image, I'm booting an Alpine Linux using network boot, copy the file.img from the network and run the dd if=file.img of=/dev/sda. This is competed successfully and if I reboot, the device boots up properly.
The issue is that I want to add some files to the new device. Naturally, I thought I'll just mount the /dev/sda2 (that's the device I want to add stuff to) and add stuff there. Well, not that simple: /dev/sda2 is missing - sometimes.
After the dd command runs, sometimes - without a pattern observed - the partitions are missing. Checking the disk using fdisk -l /dev/sda shows both partitions there.
Running partprobe /dev/sda; dmesg always shows (dmesg command outputs this) sda: sda1 sda2 so the partitions are there and they're being recognized. Still, they don't appear under /dev/.
The funny part is that running partprobe /dev/sda sometimes fixes the issue, other times it doesn't.
With all this madness, rebooting the device will ALWAYS boot correctly.
If anyone has any idea what I could try, I'd greatly appreciate the ideas.
Thank you.
P.S.:
I also tried to run partx -uv /dev/sda. That tells me:
partition: none  disk: /dev/sda, lower: 0, upper: 0
/dev/sda: partition table type 'dos' detected
/dev/sda: partition #1 added
/dev/sda: partition #2 added

But the partitions still can't be found under /dev/sdaX

What's the output of mount | grep devtmpfs?

Output of mount | grep devtmpfs: devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=498259,mode=755,inode64) 

You're dealing with something funny/unsual. Could be your kernel.

Well, it's not MY kernel, as this is the Alpine Netboot 3.19.1. I'll open an issue on the alpine project too.

As an aside, your use of dd is terribly inefficient. You will get much better throughout with a simple cat file.img >/dev/sda

@ChrisDavies I've long been using pv -petrab for that. As fast as cat but with a nice progress indicator.

@SilviuBajenaruMarcu it's down to your kernel [config]. I'm almost sure Alpine has nothing to do with that.

@ChrisDavies I'm actually using pv with dd. To be honest, I didn't know cat is faster but I'll give it a go
@ArtemS.Tashkinov well, that's what I'm saying, I don't configure anything in the kernel. I just boot alpine with whatever kernel settings it comes, dd and then try to mount the drive.
Anyways, I found that I can actually create the missing devices using mknod: mknod -m 660 /dev/sda2 b 8 2 so the problem can be considered "fixed".

@SilviuBajenaruMarcu discard the dd and just use pv. You'll be pleasantly surprised by the speed increase

@SilviuBajenaruMarcu : Consider writing up your findings and solution as an answer. You can self-accept your answer and gain reputation points after 48 hrs (Or something like that). It would be nice to be able to remove this long chain of comments (IMHO).

Even faster, especially through a network, unless running on pretty slow hardware would be piping through gzip / gunzip on backup / restore respectively, to avoid transfering huge chunks of 0s which will naturally occur on partitions with free space. So something like pv /dev/sdx | gzip >backup_location and gunzip backup_location | pv >/dev/sdx.

For anyone looking for a solution to this, you can either:

Create your device entry under /dev. An example for adding the /dev/sda2 follows:

mknod -m 660 /dev/sda2 b 8 2

Try to run

mdev -s
The 2nd command made my life easier and, so far it works without any issues. Mdev's man page:
Usage:
    mdev [-vS] 

        -v        Verbose
        -S        Log to syslog too
        -s        Scan /sys and populate /dev
        -d        Daemon, listen on netlink
        -f        Run in foreground

